# Output from email.getaddresses() not as expected

Tags: python, python-3.3

Based on the documentation on the `email.getaddresses()` module, I would expect `getaddresses('"John Doe" <johndoe@mail.com>')` to return:

```
[('John Doe', 'johndoe@mail.com')]
```

but what it returns (under Python 3.3) is:

> [('', ', J, o, h, n,  , D, o, e, '), ('', ''), ('', ''), ('', 'j'), ('', 'o'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'n'), ('', 'd'), ('', 'o'), ('', 'e'), ('', '@'), ('', 'm'), ('', 'a'), ('', 'i'), ('', 'l'), ('', '.'), ('', 'c'), ('', 'o'), ('', 'm'), ('', '')]

which is a little less than optimally useful.

What gives?

Comment: Based on http://docs.python.org/dev/library/email.util.html have you compared the behavior of `parseaddr()` and `getaddresses()`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`email.utils.getaddresses` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.getaddresses), the argument should be **a sequence of header field values**, not a single string.

```
>>> import email.utils
>>> email.utils.getaddresses(['"John Doe" <johndoe@mail.com>'])
[('John Doe', 'johndoe@mail.com')]
```